# gnuplot histogram cluster bar not displaying

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have 7 different names on the x-axis and for each 7, there are 4 corresponding y-values (4 bars),
but it is not giving me the clustered bar histogram with the script that looks like ..

```
set yrange [0:4]

set boxwidth 0.1 
set style data histograms
set style histogram cluster gap 0.1 
set style fill solid 1.0 border -1
set auto x

plot    "dataset.dat" using 2:xticlabel(1) with boxes ls 1 title col, \
        "dataset.dat" using 3:xticlabel(1) with boxes ls 2 title col, \
        "dataset.dat" using 4:xticlabel(1) with boxes ls 3 title col, \
        "dataset.dat" using 5:xticlabel(1) with boxes ls 4 title col
```

Is there something wrong with the script?

[image]

Comment: Simply remove those `with boxes`, they overrides the histogram style.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In gnuplot you have different ways to specify the actual plotting style:

- `set style data ...` sets a global default plotting style for all data plots.
- `plot ... with ...` sets a plotting style for that distinct plot. This overrides any global plotting styles.

That means, that in your example `with boxes` overrides the `set style data histogram`. Simply remove the `with boxes` parts and you get a histogram.